# Where does IIS import cert to?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5, iis-8

I am trying to replicate what IIS Import does. I have an application that needs to import the certificates programmatically but its not working because i seem to be missing a step. If i import the same certificate through IIS Import utility it works perfectly.

In code:

```
private X509Certificate2Collection x509 = new X509Certificate2Collection();
private X509Store IIS = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

x509.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
IIS.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
IIS.Add(certificate);
IIS.Close();

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + " certhash=" + CertificateThumbprint + " appid={2d967d25-4edf-4962-9b6c-5b3c4d4de48d}";
```

The netsh binding FAILS with the error `a specified logon session does not exist. it may already have been terminated`

IF i first import the certificate through the IIS manager, THEN run the netsh command, this all works just fine so i must be missing something in my code that IIS is doing in the background..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't set `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` as required, the certificate is in fact not imported to the store as you wished.

Further explanation can be found in [KB950090](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/950090/installing-a-pfx-file-using-x509certificate-from-a-standard-net-applic)

Comment: That was exactly the issue! Thanks